# Big-O Algebra Simplification Issue

Tags: big-o

I've been working on a problem for several hours now, and I need clarification:

I needed to simplify (as much as possible) the following big-O expressions. For each, I put down what I thought was the correct answer. I would like solutions, but I would appreciate an explanation as well if I am incorrect. I am trying to learn Big O notation as well as possible, and I think doing these problems helped a lot. I just want to make sure I'm on the right path.

a) `O(sqrt(n) + log(n)*log(n))`

I thought this was `O(n)`

b) `O(3log2 n + 2log3 n)`

I thought this was `O(log3 (n))`

c) `O(n^3 + 2n^2 +3n + 4)`

I thought this was `O(n^3)`

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Looks like you're on the right path. You may want to ask this type of question to cs.stackexchange in the future.

Comment: Oh, thanks AndyG, I'm new to the site, I'll remember next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through this one at a time.

> O(sqrt(n) + log(n)*log(n)). I thought this was **O(n)**

You are correct that this is O(n), but that's not a particularly tight bound. Let's start with a simplifying question: which grows faster, O(sqrt(n)) or O(log(n) * log(n))? Using that information, can you drop one of the two terms from the summation?

> O(3log2 n + 2log3 n). I thought this was **O(log3 (n))**

Remember that "big-O ignores the base of logarithms" (that is, log<sub>b</sub> n = O(log<sub>c</sub> n) for any b and c that are greater than one). You're technically right that it's O(log3 n), but that's not the cleanest solution. You'd be better off saying O(log n) here.

> O(n^3 + 2n^2 +3n + 4). I thought this was **O(n^3)**

Exactly right! This works because 2n<sup>2</sup> + 3n + 4 is O(n<sup>3</sup>), so you can drop those terms from the summation. Now, can you use a similar trick to simplify your answer to part (a)?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Clarification: O(sqrt(n) + log(n)*log(n)) is not O(n). The first is a subset of the latter, but they are not equal. E.g. T(n) = n is in O(n) but not in O(sqrt(n) + log(n)*log(n)).

Comment: It technically is. Big Oh only defines upperbound. That's why it is said "*that's not a particularly tight bound*".

Comment: @luk32 No, it's not. Functions that fulfill the loose bound of O(n) do not necessarily fulfill a tighter bound. Therefore, both sets cannot be equal.

Comment: Everything that is `O(sqrt(n) + log(n)*log(n))` is also `O(n)` precisely because first is a subset of the latter. Nobody says it's equal. It is "bounded  from above".

Comment: @luk32 Well, as far as I know, the meaning of "a is b" is: "a is equal to b" and not "a is a subset of b". Please be careful with your wording.

Comment: I do agree, It does depend on how you read it, but most people use it in the meaning that when `f` is `O(g)` it means `f` belongs to `O(g)`. I don't think the fact that `f` is `O(f)` changes meaning. Anyway people are very inconsistent and loose with `big O` naming conventions, and there is no standard. I personally never use this "f = O(g)" because it does not make sense. I actually don't like this answer because it uses confusing wording and does not define precisely what is being meant. The same thing is discussed on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Equals_sign).

Comment: @NicoSchertler I think this is one of those unfortunate cases of ambiguous notation. I've usually seen the statement "O(f) is O(g)" to mean "any function that is O(f) is also O(g)," and that's the meaning I've tried to use here. I've usually seen "the class of functions O(f) is the same as the class of functions O(g)" or "O(f) = O(g)" to indicate the stronger claim that all functions that are O(f) are O(g) and vice-versa. Sorry for the ambiguity!

Comment: I understand the discussion with the ambiguous notation (as well as a high school student taking an advanced CS class at a university can), so in the end, for a), the tighter bound would be O(n^1/2) vs O(n), correct? BTW thanks a lot for the explanation, this one truly makes me understand it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the answer is long but I was pretty throughout.

**Intro:**
1st thing you need to do is to properly define what you mean by big O. [Relevant read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations). Traditionally it's defined only as upper bound. But it's not very useful in computer science, at least not for task such as yours. You could technically answer with anything growing faster than example i.e. saying `O(n!)` for all the questions would technically be ok.

More useful is big theta, and usually in CS I saw big O redefined to the meaning of big Theta from the read above. The difference is that your bound, must be tighter and also apply from below.

**Definitions/Rules:** My favourite method to calculate Big O (and Theta) is using limits. It allows to sum asymptotic behaviour relations in a simple and straight forward manner.

Basically if (`x->inf` is implied here and thereafter):

1. `lim f(x) / g(x) = infinity` - f asymptotically grows bigger than g
2. `lim f(x) / g(x) is a constant > 0` - f asymptotically grows the same as g
3. `lim f(x) / g(x) = 0` - f asymptotically grows slower than g

Number 2. is big Theta. Number 2. and 3. combined are traditional Big O as in "`f` belongs to `O(g)`" (or "*is* `O(g)`" which is somewhat confusing wording). It means that `f` will not outgrow `g` so `g` is its upper bound.

Now with a little math is pretty easy to prove that Big O (or Theta) will care only about the fastest growing term. This comes straight from limit properties.

*I will use `O` as big Theta from now on because everything holds for Big O too as it is looser.*

**Explanation of examples:**
Your 3rd example is the easiest. You can safely drop `2n^2 +3n + 4` because `n^3` is growing faster. You can prove that `n^3 + 2n^2 +3n + 4` is `O(n^3)` it by calculating `lim n^3 / (n^3 + 2n^2 +3n + 4)`.

Same goes for your 2nd exaple, but you need to go through logarithm properties. Basically:

`log b1 (x) = c log b2 (x)` - it means you can switch the base of logarithm at the expense of a constant... and from above rules definition a constant factor does not change anything, it's still 2. just the constant changes.

Your 1st example is hardest/trickiest, because the limit is most complicated. However, `O(f+g)` *is* either `O(f)` or `O(g)`, because either one grows faster, so the other can be dropped or they asymptotically grow the same so either one can be chosen (their fastest growing term will be the same anyways). This means you need to check which one is growing faster, you do this by ... calculating `lim sqrt(n)/(log(n)*log(n))` and choosing according to rules from above. I think this one needs d'Hospital rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reading + explanation, VERY helpful for me (a high-school student taking CS classes at a University)

Answer (score 0):

(a) is the toughest one there I think; (b) and (c) use fairly common rules for Big-Oh simplification.

For (a), I suggest making a substition: let m = [some function of n that makes one of the two terms simpler] and rearrange to get n = [something].  You can then use this to substitute m into the expression, thereby getting rid of all appearances of n, and simplify it according to Big-Oh rules.  Then, provided that the function you picked is an increasing function of n, you can substitute n back in and simplify further if need be.