# Prove for 928675*2^n=0(2^n) Big-0notation complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, big-o, proof

I am supposed to Prove that 92675*2^n=0(2^n) and use the mathematical definition of 0(f(n)). I came up with following answer not sure if this is the right way to approach it though

<strike>Answer: Since 92875 is a constant, we can replace it with K and F(n)=K+2n therefore O(f(n)=O(K+2n)  and since K is a constant it can be taken away from the formula and we are therefore left with O(f(n)=O(2n)</strike>

Can someone please confirm if this is right or not?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Just realized that I wrote + instead of * and forgot a couple of ^ signs

Answer: Since 92675 is a constant, we can replace it with K and F(n)=K*2^n therefore O(f(n)=O(K*2^n)  and since K is a constant it can be taken away from the formula and we are therefore left with O(f(n)=O(2n)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Constant "928675" won't affect situation when n will become big.

Comment: Can you please check if the answer  is correct with the edit @QtRoS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178877/big-o-algebra-simplification-issue/28180125#28180125 **Definition/Rules** 2.

Comment: You are using `O(f(x)) = O(k*f(x))` to prove that `O(k*f(x)) = O(f(x))`. That's a tautology.

Comment: Being explicit: your answer does not prove it. You are supposed to use the big-o definition.

Comment: `>>Flag pls I must take this down now okay i will take this down now<<` Is this `jeopardy` and I have to guess the original question? You make your question useless for other people if you edit your question like a chat without history.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to prove exactly that proposition (`O(f(n))=O(K*2^n)`). You can't use it to prove itself.

The definition of `f(x) is O(g(x))` is that, for some constant real numbers `k` and `x_0`, `|f(x)| <= |k*g(x)|` for `x>=x_0`.

That's why if `f(x) = k*g(x)` we can say that `f(x) is O(g(x))` (`|k*g(x)| <= |k*g(x)|` for any `x`). In special, it is also true for `g(x)=2^x` and `k=928675`.