# Big O Notation: Definition

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I've been watching MIT lectures for the algorithms course and the definition for the Big O notation says
f(n) = O(g(n)) such that for some constants c and n<sub>0</sub>
0 < f(n) < c.g(n) for all n>n<sub>0</sub>

Then the instructor proceeded to give an example,
2n<sup>2</sup>=O(n<sup>3</sup>)

Now I get that Big O gives the upper bound on the function but I am confused as to what exactly does the function f(n) correspond to here? What is its significance? As per my understanding goes, g(n) is the function representing the algorithm we are trying to analyse, but what is the purpose of f(n) or as in the example 2n<sup>2</sup>?

Need some clarification on this, I've been stuck here for hours.

Comment: If n is the variable of the function, then 2x^2 is either undefined, or constant with regard to n if x was defined as a number somewhere. More likely, this is a typo and it's supposed to read "2n^2 = O(n^3)".

Comment: I'm not capable of providing an answer, but in my opinion this question is more suited to the computer science site http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @G.Bach I'm sorry, that was a mistake. It is 2n^2. I'll fix it.

Comment: Would this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178877/big-o-algebra-simplification-issue ?

Comment: @luk32 I get the concept of finding the Big O of a function by omitting the lower powers and constants. However, I was confused by the usage of the functions in the definitions. As in which is which, and which functions correspond to the algorithm itself & which functions correspond to the time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the formal definition of big-O notation, the functions f(n) and g(n) are placeholders for other functions, the same way that, say, in the quadratic formula, the letters a, b, and c are placeholders for the actual coefficients in the quadratic equation.

In your example, the instructor was talking about how 2n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>3</sup>). You have a formal definition that talks about what it means, in general, for f(n) = O(g(n)) to be true. So let's pattern-match that against the math above. It looks like f(n) is the thing on the left and g(n) is the thing on the right, so in this example f(n) = 2n<sup>2</sup> and g(n) = n<sup>3</sup>.

The previous paragraph gives a superficial explanation of what f(n) and g(n) are by just looking at one example, but it's better to talk about what they really *mean*. Mathematically, f(n) and g(n) really can be any functions you'd like, but typically when you're using big-O notation in the context of the analysis of algorithms, you'll usually let f(n) be the true amount of work done by the algorithm in question (or its runtime, or its space usage, or really just about anything else) and will pick g(n) to be some "nice" function that's easier to reason about. For example, it might be the case that some function you're analyzing has a true runtime, as a function of n, as 16n<sup>3</sup> - 2n<sup>2</sup> - 9n + 137. That would be your function f(n). Since the whole point behind big-O notation is to be able to (mathematically rigorously and safely) discard constant factors and low-order terms, we'll try to pick a g(n) that grows at the same rate as f(n) but is easier to reason about - say, g(n) = n<sup>3</sup>. So now we can try to determine whether f(n) = O(g(n)) by seeing whether we can find the constants c and n<sub>0</sub> talked about in the formal definition of big-O notation.

So to recap:

- f(n) and g(n) in the definition given are just placeholders for other functions.
- In practical usage, f(n) will be the true runtime of the algorithm in question, and g(n) will be something a lot simpler that grows at the same rate.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. This makes proper sense.

Answer (score 0):

`f(n)` is the function that gives you the exact values of the thing you are trying to measure (be that time, number of processor instructions, number of iterations steps, amount of memory used, whatever).

`g(n)` is another function that approximates the growth of `f(n)`.

In the usual case you don't really know f(n) or it's really hard to compute. For example for time it depends on the processor speed, memory access patterns, system load, compiler optimizations and other. `g(n)` is usually really simple and it's easier to understand if f(n) = O(N) that if you double n you will roughly double the runtime, in the worst case. Since it's an upper bound `g(n)` doesn't have to be the minimum, but usually people try to avoid inflating it if it's not necessary. In your example O(n^3) is an upper bound for 2n^2, but so is O(n^2) and O(n!).

Comment: OK. So correct me if I am wrong. f(n) is supposedly the exact solution (time complexity in this case) and g(n) is the upper/lower bounding approximate solution. As in this case, 2n^2 would have been the exact time (had we not known) complexity but O(n^3) is also the accepted (but a less accurate) time complexity.

Comment: Good answer. But hmm I disagree with part of that last paragraph. f(n) does not depend on proccessor speed or memory patterns or anything else - it is a function of n *in the algorithm*. The algorithm is independent of its implementation, usually. Sure Knuth and others will even analyze it for a particular implementation of something like matrix multiplication, but I've never seen it given as a function of the machine its running on (that would be largely useless, right?)

Comment: In fact, as written, it is almost notationally incorrect to say it's also a function of system load - that would be f(n,Ps,Mp,Sl), etc. If we write f(n), we have a function of only one variable, right?

Comment: Just one more comment ( :) ), there are even sometimes when O-notation isn't entirely practical - like conceptual matrix multiplication where the coefficient is more important than the exponent - in this cases, we actually might care what f(n) is, but we probably don't care what f(n,Ps,Mp,Si) is on a conceptual level